# Count show Zero if there is no value in SQL with some condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables One is events and second is registration.
I have stored active or past event details in My events table.

First Table for events:

```
*-----------------------------------------------------*
| Event_id | Event_name |  Event_end_date  |  Status  |
*-----------------------------------------------------*
|   E001   |    AHM     | 2019-02-05 10:00 |   Past   |
|   E002   |    JPS     | 2019-03-14 10:00 |  Active  |
|   E003   |    AHM     | 2019-02-05 10:00 |  Active  |
*-----------------------------------------------------*
```

Second table for registration information:

```
*------------------------------------*
| R_no | Event_id |   booking_date   |
*------------------------------------*
|  101 |   E001   | 2019-02-01 17:00 |
|  102 |   E001   | 2018-11-19 18:50 |
|  101 |   E002   | 2018-12-09 14:00 |
|  102 |   E002   | 2019-01-25 08:50 |
|  103 |   E002   | 2019-02-05 18:00 |
|  101 |   E003   | 2019-02-08 10:00 |
|  102 |   E003   | 2019-02-10 13:00 |
|  103 |   E003   | 2019-02-12 14:50 |
|  104 |   E003   | 2019-02-14 16:00 |
*------------------------------------*
```

Now I want the output as below for event E003, Here should be noted that there is no booking on 2018-Dec and 2019-Jan for E003 but as per registration table there is one active event E002 and some tickets books on 2018-Dec and 2019-Jan and this depends on event_end_date.

```
*-----------------*
|  Month  | Count |
*-----------------*
| 2018-12 |   0   |
| 2019-01 |   0   |
| 2019-02 |   4   |
*-----------------*
```

I am able to get the count for 2019-02 but not able for Dec and Jan. I am using the below query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, "%Y-%m") As month, count(event_id) AS count FROM registration LEFT JOIN events ON registration.event_id = events.event_id WHERE registration.event_id = 'E003' GROUP BY registration.event_id
```

So any update on my query so that I can get my output.

Comment: no data -> nothing to select --> you need a general time period table (2018012, 2019001, 2019002 etc.) with which you could join your queries with

Answer (score 0):

You can use `correlated subquery` with `not exists`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, "%Y-%m") As month, count(event_id) AS count 
FROM registration LEFT JOIN events ON registration.event_id = events.event_id 
WHERE registration.event_id = 'E003' and not exists
(select 1 from registration b where registration.event_id=b.event_id and Status='Past')
GROUP BY registration.event_id
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but my between date is not fixed, it depends on active events registration booking date.

Comment: @SantoshKhatri, edited the answer - you can check now

Comment: Sorry but it is not showing the count of Dec, jan, it is giving me only 4 count for 2019-02. and please ignore the status="past", this column is removed from my column.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query -

```
select
t1.book_year_month, count(*) FROM events t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( 
                SELECT DISTINCT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(booking_date), '%Y-%m') book_year_month, 
                                booking_date from events) t2 ON t2.booking_date<=t1.event_end_date GROUP BY t2.book_year_month;
```

Comment: i do not have book_year_month column in events table.

Comment: Book_year_month will be derived from booking date column of events table... I have corrected my query please.. check noq

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `LEFT JOIN` and filtering like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%Y-%m') As month,  
       COUNT(event_id) AS count
FROM registration r LEFT JOIN
     events e
     ON e.event_id = r.event_id AND
        e.event_id = 'E003'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%Y-%m');
```

Comment: your query is showing only count for 2019-02, but i want the count for 2018-12 and 2019-01, In this months no tickets books so the count should be come zero.

Comment: @SantoshKhatri . . . This should have every month in the registration table.  That is how `LEFT JOIN` works.

Comment: @GordenLinoff Right, but i have a condition that i do not have any tickets on those days  but for active event the last ticket booked on dec.